# I want to pull data from Google analytics 4 to Google Sheets. How can I do it?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I was thinking of using the API to pull the data from GA4 to google sheets. but I could not be able to pull data. And more importantly, I want to pull custom events data. Can anyone help me with this problem?

We tried to pull custom events data but it is just been able to pull only google's original event like pageview etc.

Comment: Do you have more information on what you have tried?

Comment: For me, the fastest way is using `google app script` from google sheet and write the JS code to pull the GA4 data into google sheet.